# Cannot capture the image of the ios application

Tags: ios, image, capture, ipa, charles-proxy

The Audible app will show 3 guidance images just like the attachment [one of the 3 iamges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMGW4.jpg) before we sign in.I want to capture the 3 pictures with **Charles** tool,but failed (no image-url).Then I downloaded the app with iTunes, and searched the 3 pictures through hundreds of pictures in the ipa file, but didn't find.

Can you tell me whether the 3 images are requested from the server when we open the app for the first time? or the 3 images are just put with other images together in the ipa file？And how to get the pictures?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need them? I'm no expert, but it may be illegal to get them.

Comment: I just need the 3 images to complete a demo.

Comment: Then just grab screenshots of them.

Comment: no no no, I need the origin image without other UIcontrols on it. A little obsessive.